# What does the C do in Image Processing's Logarithmic Transformation do?

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing

Log Transform for image is defined as this

```
s=T(r) = c*log(r+1)
```

where

```
s is the output image
r is the input image 
c = 255/log(1+Maximum pixel value from the input image).
```

If the "Maximum pixel value from the input image" is 255 then the C value will be

```
105.886458025=255/log(256)
```

This does not make sense. 105.89 is a very high intensity value. Multiplying with this C value will yield a very bright image. Using the 'tire' image from matlab I get the output below:

```
I=imread('tire.tif'); 
I2=im2double(I); 
J=105*log(1+I2);
imshow(I)
```

[image]

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Which logarithm base do they mean by `log`?

Comment: @MarkRansom My explanation is based on here- https://pythontic.com/image-processing/pillow/logarithmic%20transformation#:~:text='c'%20is%20the%20scaling%20constant,range%20of%200%20to%202.41. No base were specified, so base 10 i suppose?

Comment: The reference you linked is explicit about using base 10, and that's what you used to calculate `c`.  But what base does matlab use by default?

Comment: And does matlab use the range of 0-255 or 0.0-1.0?

Comment: `c*log(r+1) = log(r+1) * 255 / log(1+Maximum pixel value from the input image) = 255 * log(1+r) / log(1+imax)` and now you might smell that this is simply a scale factor and the result is `255 * [0..1]`, because 0 <= r <= imax -- I don't see the challenge in figuring that out. did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: `im2double` converts the image to a range [0,1]. So max value is 1, not 255.

Comment: @CrisLuengo then the proper value of `c` would be `3.3219`, not `105`.  No wonder the output is almost white!

Comment: @user1535147 This turned out to be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @user1535147 The value of c is correct. Your Matlab implementation had problems.

Answer (score 1):

### Image for demonstration

[image: Raw image of forest] [image: Processed image of forest]

### Alternate image

[image: Raw image of a swan] [image: Bright, sparkling, clear image of a swan]

`c` is a scaling factor.

The following script works both on Matlab and Octave.

```matlab
clc;
close all;
clearvars;
%imageFileName = 'https://www.forestfoliage.com/wp-content/original/2010_10/Fall-Foliage-mountain-sunset.jpg';
imageFileName = 'https://pixnio.com/free-images/2020/06/27/2020-06-27-11-50-57-1200x800.jpg';
I = imread(imageFileName);
inputMin = min(I(:))
inputMax = max(I(:))
I2 = double(I);
outputMax = 255
c = outputMax/log10(1 + double(inputMax))
J = uint8(double(c) * log10(1 + I2));

%I2(1:5,1:5,:)
%J(1:5,1:5,:)

imshow(I)
title("Raw")
pause(5)
imshow(J)
title("Processed")
```

[im2double documentation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html):

> im2double(I) converts the image I to double precision. I can be a grayscale intensity image, a truecolor image, or a binary image. im2double rescales the output from integer data types to the range [0, 1].

So, we will use double() instead. Thanks to @CrisLuengo for this. Earlier, I was rescaling the scaled output.

In Matlab,
**Images stored as matrices of type double should have values in the range [0, 1].**
**Images stored as integer matrices should have values in the range [0, 255].**

On line 12, we are casting the matrix to an integer matrix for this reason.
From the [imshow() documentation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#d123e182551),

> If you specify a truecolor image of data type single or double, then values should be in the range [0, 1]. If pixel values are outside this range, then you can use the rescale function to scale pixel values to the range [0, 1]. The 'DisplayRange' argument has no effect when the input image is truecolor.